# How to download a specific git tree or commit after force push

Tags: git, github, version-control

I pushed the commit with `-force` without thinking about the consequences, but I do have all of the previous commits from an old Pull Request and I can still see the files and their commits. My question is, is it possible to download the repository even if all of the commits have been reset but there are still commits from an old Pull Request?

Say for example I would like to download the repository from this link 
https://github.com/organizaton/repo.github.io/commits/99fb22467f90a18be7e00aa1d51743bb4af20a43

Is it possible to download the repository files like that?

The current repository sees only 2 commits, but previously, there was a fair amount of them. I'm wondering if I can return them back?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From inside your local repository you can fetch a github *pull request* like this:

`git fetch origin pull/ID/head:newbranchname`

e.g. with `1` in place of `ID` 
 for *pull request #1*

After that you can happily switch branch with `git checkout newbranchname` and inspect your recovered treasure with `git log`

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have them locally. So if I do `git fetch <URL-with-the-commit>` it should download the all the files along with the commit history?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Tried like that, it throws parse errors. Anyways, here is the link with the commit that I'm trying to download along with the commit history https://github.com/ktzkikinda/ktzkikinda.github.io/commits/99fb22467f90a18be7e00aa1d51743bb4af20a43 , but that same repo now show **2 commits** instead of **17**. What's the exact git command to download the repo with that timestamp with all of the commit history?

Comment: I'm receiving `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` when trying to run `git fetch https://github.com/ktzkikinda/ktzkikinda.github.io/pull/1head`

Comment: You sir, are a king!!! MY thankfulness is infinite. You saved from the biggest whole of misery. I wan't to get in contact with you through the e-mail. How can I contact you?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you pushed with force, the remote repository works the same way than your local one, and have received the same objects, which persist for a while.

What I would do is to perform a

```
git reflog <branch>
```

… onto the branch you've performed the `push --force` from, and try to retrieve the hash sum of the last commit in date before you do. If you can't find it from here (because you branch would probably have diverged from a long time before you push it), you can try to retrieve the remote reflog through the Github's event API :

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<your account>/<your repository>/events
```

Once you get this sum, create a tag pointing onto the commit's hash sum

```
git tag <tagname> <hash>
```

Then push the lineage onto the server

```
git push origin <tagname>
```

Since everything should still already be on server (only unreferenced), this should be immediate. You'll then be able to browse the old history without altering the current state of your production branches.

Docs about Github's API:

- https://medium.com/git-tips/githubs-reflog-a9ff21ff765f
- https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-issue-events-for-a-repository